# Grails data binding - command objects with Lists

Tags: grails, grails-controller

Grails 1.3.7

Trouble with data binding Command objects that have List content.  Example Command:

```
class Tracker {
    String name
    String description
    List<Unit> units = new ArrayList()
}

class Unit {
    String name
    Long unitMax
    Long unitMin
}
```

create GSP for Tracker has the Unit fields.  One example:

```
<g:textField name="units[0].unitMax" value=""/>
```

TrackerController save method:

```
 def save = { Tracker trackerInstance ->
   trackerInstance = trackingService.saveOrUpdateTracker(trackerInstance)
 }
```

But, always java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Alternatively, if I update controller to:

```
def save = {
   Tracker trackerInstance = new Tracker()
   trackerInstance.properties = params
   ....
```

Then groovy.lang.ReadOnlyPropertyException: Cannot set readonly property: properties for class: com.redbrickhealth.dto.Tracker
Any ideas?

There seems to be a difference between binding in GORM vs Command objects.

Maybe I need to extend and register a PropertyEditorSupport for Unit?

-Todd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grails requires an command with existing list, that will be filled with data from reques.

If you know exact number of units, say 3, you can:

```
class Tracker {
    String name
    String description
    List<Unit> units = [new Unit(), new Unit(), new Unit()]
}
```

or use LazyList from apache commons collections

```
import org.apache.commons.collections.ListUtils
import org.apache.commons.collections.Factory
class Tracker {
    String name
    String description
    List<Unit> units = ListUtils.lazyList([], {new Unit()} as Factory)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Since Groovy 1.8.7 the `List` interface has a method called `withLazyDefault` that can be used instead of apache commons `ListUtils`:

```
List<Unit> units = [].withLazyDefault { new Unit() }
```

This creates a new `Unit` instance every time `units` is accessed with a non-existent index.

See the [documentation of withLazyDefault](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html#withLazyDefault%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) for more details. I also wrote a small [blog post](http://www.mscharhag.com/2013/09/grails-data-binding-with-lists.html) about this a few days ago.