# Binding multiple checkboxes to list in Grails

Tags: list, grails, binding, checkbox

It seems simple but is apparently very hard. Bind a (finite and known length) series of checkboxes to a list of booleans on a grails command object. It should of course be possible to "populate" the command object to restore the view, with the previous selected values.

E.g I have a grails webflow. It start out by binding 4 checkboxes to an entry in a boolean list. It switches to next state and prints the values - e.g. [true,true]. Navigate back, and all the checkboxes are empty (which makes perfectly sense - 4 checkboxes and only two values). So it should rather be e.g. [false, true, false, true].

No matter what I do, I cant seem to make this happen. In spring it would be easy, simply bind the checkbox to value[0]..[3]... Why is somehthing this simple so hard in Grails?!

Please help, it would really make my day!

Example Command Obj:

```
class TestCmdObj {    
    List<Boolean> boolListOne = []
}
```

Example binding method in controller (closure executed in flow action):

```
private def doBindAndValidateBoolList = {       
    bindData(flow.testCmdObj, params, [include:['boolListOne']])
}
```

So far so good. This actually works when displaying next page in flow, the testCmdObj.boolListOne displays true for the checkboxes checked..

The GSP code is simple, and uses:

```
<g:checkBox name="boolListOne"/>
<g:checkBox name="boolListOne"/>
<g:checkBox name="boolListOne"/>
<g:checkBox name="boolListOne"/>
```

In the next view, I can print out ${testCmdObj.boolListOne} and it prints out as many "true" values, as I checked of..(e.g. [true, true]) If I navigate back, the checkboxes are emtpy... Which, again, I can understand, since they all have the same name...

Comment: Add the source of your command.

Comment: which source? The one that doesn't work? Which try then? .. Alright, i'll post some source code... :)

Comment: Yep, it makes easy see what's going on :)

Comment: Hehe, yeah I know.. I just have tried so much, I was wondering which source code to post.. I'll post you my most successful try :)

Comment: Post the command object you are trying to bind to and the HTML you are using

Comment: There u go - hope you can provide me with some help :)

Comment: Well.. I kinda see the problem now. Its a matter of proper use of "fieldValue" to inspect the bean to set the values of the checkboxes when navigating back... However I cant individually seem to "match" the names in a list... like <g:checkbox name="boolListOne[0]" />

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so taking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709864/grails-data-binding-command-objects-with-lists) as reference:

> Grails requires an command with existing list, that will be filled
>   with data from reques.

So what you need to do is:

<strike>class TestCmdObj {

        List boolListOne = ListUtils.lazyList([], FactoryUtils.instantiateFactory(Boolean) )
    }</strike>

Also, your gsp will need to iterate over your command to show every entry, like:

```
<g:each in="${myCommandInstance.boolListOne}" var="boolInstance" status="i">
<g:checkbox name="boolListOne[${i}]" value="${boolInstance}" />
</g:each>
```

With this, every checkbox in your gsp will correspond as one entry in the list.

**EDIT**: It seems that for wrappers of primitive types there's no need for use the factory.

Comment: It wont accept the factory construction... "not method applicable for ... $_closure ... ". So it seems it wont accept the Facory/closure construction.. Have you ever tried this?

Comment: No, I didn't tested because I used this sometimes. Looking at my codes this is a little different, see the edit using FactoryUtils.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to finalise all in between the above suggestions / comments.

1. If you declare an iteration of checkboxes and callthem

```
<g:each in="someIteration" var="a">
  <g:checkBox name="something" value="${a.someCondition}" 
  checked="${a.someCondition}" />
</g:each>
```

Your controller in grails will pick up this up as 
`String[L]`
A bit like a validation object of `String[] something`
Although you would still declare this as `List something=[]`.

This also appears to work so long as the end user has selected more than 1 checkbox. and your validation object would pickup at this point  `List something=[]`

The issue with above is that if 1 selection is made the param is received more as a `string` than a `list`

Nothing wrong with above if you are not relying on auto binding of objects since you would do

`List myList = params.list('something')`

at this point grails will convert whether 1 or multiple into the list. But this won't bind a single checkbox to a validation list element.

To fix this from a validation point of view would be to declare it as `List something=[]`

```
<g:each in="someIteration" status="i" var="a">
  <g:checkBox name="something[${i}]" value="${a.someCondition}" 
   checked="${a.someCondition}" />
</g:each>
```

Now this will be picked up under `something` list like `['null','whatever','null','null']` regardless of 1 selection or multiple check box selection.

It is to use the `status` field and rename name from `something` to `something[${i}]`