# Create dynamic table with webflow and grails

Tags: grails, groovy, spring-webflow

I'm trying to create a webflow with a dynamic table on one page. Which looks like this

```
 def startFlow = {

    contact {
        on('next') {
            flow.developer = params.developer
            flow.project = params.project
            flow.division = params.division
            flow.projectResponsible = params.projectResponsible
            flow.email = params.email

            [flow : flow]
        }.to('ipcount')
        on('cancel').to('finish')
    }
    ipcount{
        on('next'){
            flow.ipcount = params.int('ipcount')

            [flow: flow]
        }.to('systems')
        on('cancel').to('finish')
    }
    systems{
        on('next') {
            flow.hoster= params.hoster
            flow.ip = params.ip
            flow.os = params.os
            flow.dns = params.dns
            flow.systemDate = params.systemDate

            [flow : flow]
        }.to('url')
        on('cancel').to('finish')
    } ....
```

The problem is I that the number of systems could be different every time (1...n).
One idea was to ask the page before how many entries should be created (ipcount).

My view looks like this

```
  <g:set var="count" value="${flow.ipcount}" />
                 <g:each in="${(1..'${count}')}">
                  <tr class="prop">
                    <td valign="top" class="name">
                        <label for="ip">IP Adresse:</label>
                    </td>
                   <td valign="top">
                    <td valign="top" class="value ${hasErrors(bean:hosterInstance,field:'ip','errors')}">
                        <input type="text" id="ip" name="ip" value="${params.ip}" />
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top" class="name">
                        <label for="dns">DNS:</label>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top">
                        <input type="text" id="dns" name="dns" value="${params.dns}" />
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top" class="name">
                        <label for="os">Operating System:</label>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top">
                        <input type="text" id="dns" name="dns" value="${params.os}" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
               </g:each>
```

Beside that this is not working as I get an Internal server error: (java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer) it would be nicer if I could at the table row dynamically on the page. 
Here is the question: Is this possible with webflow and how? Especially I don't know how to handle the flow parameter and how to save the collected entries at the end of the webflow to the database.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to work with a list of objects, [command objects](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#commandObjects) is the way to go. It supports databinding from the incoming request and will handle lists.

You can check [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709864/grails-data-binding-command-objects-with-lists) that show's you how to do it.

And in your view, you will need to handle the index in the name of your input. Example:

Consider

```
class System {
  String ip
  String dns
  ...
}
```

And `commandInstance.systems` a `List<System>`.

```
<g:each in="${commandInstance.systems}" var="command" status="i">

  <input type="text" id="ip$i" name="systems[$i].ip" value="${command.ip}" />

</g:each>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your answer. How do I define the number of entries that are displayed? If I understand your code this renders all fields for one Instance.

Comment: I edited my variable name to make more sense to you. I'm looping though the list of systems and printing his properties.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. That makes it clearer. But that is not the problem I have. I have not a list of systems. I have a form created with webflow and want to create new entries and how to handle them in the webflow.

Comment: You want to create just one new instance or a List? Anyway, in both cases you can attach the command in your webflow. If you need more than one instance, just use the name of the property with the index: command[0].ip, command[1].ip...